# Where is the \n coming from when I write to a file?

Tags: c

I'm probably missing something obvious, but every time I write to a file, the inputted text is on the second line of the document when I open it. What is causing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    char filename[100];
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Type the name of the file to write to followed by enter: \n\n");

    scanf("%[^\t\n]s", filename); 

    fp = fopen(filename, "w");

    printf("\n\nEnter the text you wish to write to this file: \n\n");

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        putc(c, fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've told `scanf` not to eat any `\n` characters, so there will still be one sitting in the input buffer when you start the loop with <s>`putc`</s> `getchar`.

One solution would be to precede the loop with a call to <s>`putc`</s> `getchar` to eat the `\n`.

Comment: what would be the argument in the putc call to remove the \n?

Comment: @stariz77: Sorry, that was a typo.  I meant `getchar`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `scanf` didn't consume the `'\n'` (or `'\t'`).

Try specifying the filename with a tab: `"filename<TAB>first line<ENTER>"` :)

---

To get rid of the ENTER, use

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) /* void */;
if (ch == EOF) /* no more input; abort or whatever */;
```